# same search filter for 2 tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use same search filter for two tables. now its only working for one table

```
var $rows1 = $('#dev-table tbody tr ');
$('#dev-table-filter ').keyup(function () {
    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;
    $rows1.show().filter(function () {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
});

var $rows2 = $('#nav-table tbody tr ');
$('#dev-table-filter ').keyup(function () {
    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;
    $rows2.show().filter(function () {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
});
```

this is my html code , I think this will help to understand the problem

```
 <div class="panel panel-primaray table-responsive" style="border-color:none !important">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dev-table-filter" data-action="filter" data-filters="#dev-table"
                                           placeholder="Search by your will" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body ">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dev-table">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr style="color: #0078AA">
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center">Airline</th>
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center">Airline Code</th>
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center">Checked Baggage (At a cost)</th>
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center">Hand Baggage</th>
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center">Child Hand Baggage Allowance</th>
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center">First/Business</th>
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center">Frequent Flyer</th>
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center">Excess Charge</th>
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center">Airline Page</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody class="atag">

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="text-center heading-row" colspan="9">Low Cost Carriers</td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="142">cell</td>
                                                    <td width="84">cell</td>
                                                    <td width="183">cell</td>
                                                    <td width="412">cell</td>
                                                    <td width="200">cell</td>
                                                    <td width="95">-</td>
                                                    <td width="99">-</td>
                                                    <td width="94">-</td>
                                                    <td class="bagss" align="center" height="35">
                                                        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                                           cell
                                                        </a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr> 
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>cell</td>
                                                    <td>cell</td>
                                                    <td>cell</td>
                                                    <td>cell</td>
                                                    <td>cell</td>
                                                    <td>-</td>
                                                    <td>-</td>
                                                    <td>-</td>
                                                    <td class="bagss" align="center" height="35">
                                                        <a href="#"
                                                           target="_blank">cell</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered " id=" nav-table">
                                            <thead >
                                                <tr id="myP" style="color: #0078AA">
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center" id="tr1">Airline</th>
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center" id="tr2">Airline <br />Code</th>
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center" id="tr3">Checked Baggage</th>
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center" id="tr4">Hand Baggage</th>
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center" id="tr5">Child Allowance</th>
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center" id="tr6">First/Business</th>
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center" id="tr7">Frequent Flyer</th>
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center" id="tr8">Excess Charge</th>
                                                    <th align="center" class="text-center" id="tr9">Airline Page</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody class="atag">
                                                <tr style="color: #0078AA">
                                                    <td colspan="9" class="text-center heading-row">A</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" width="115" class="bagss">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" width="57" class="bagss">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" width="114" class="bagss">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" width="92" class="bagss">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" width="74" class="bagss">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" width="94" class="bagss">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" width="81" class="bagss"></td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" width="126" class="bagss">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" width="114" class="bagss">
                                                        <a target="_blank"
                                                           href="#">
                                                            cell
                                                        </a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bags">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bags">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bags">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bags">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bags">2cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bags">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bags">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bags">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bags">
                                                        <a target="_blank"
                                                           href="#">
                                                            cell
                                                        </a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bagss">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bagss">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bagss">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bagss">5cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bagss">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bagss">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bagss">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bagss">cell</td>
                                                    <td align="center" height="35" class="bagss">
                                                        <a target="_blank"
                                                           href="#">
                                                            cell
                                                        </a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>

                                </div>



                            </div>
```

I'm highly struggled with this.please help me with this.hope your help.thanx

Comment: format you code properly first

Comment: You have 2 `keyup` events on same table. hence it only works on 1 table

Answer (score 2):

You have used same `ID` ,thats the reason  its working for only one

> `ID` should be unique always

Use different `ID` or `Class` Instead.

```
$('#dev-table-filter ').keyup( /*same ID used*/
```

Comment: make a jsfiddle what you tried ,, you must be doing something wrong..please make a jsfiddle.in

Answer (score 1):

You can make a common function and pass the id of the table with that function like :

```
function search(id){
    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
    text;

   id.show().filter(function () {
         text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
         return !reg.test(text);
   }).hide();
}
```

and in your keyup function you can call it like

```
$('#dev-table-filter ').keyup(function () {
   search($('#dev-table tbody tr '));
});
```

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same ID for `.keyup` here. Please add the particular element's id after the id:

```
$('#dev-table-filter ').keyup(
//-------------------^ Add the respective element here
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you are missing `keyup` event on `nav-table`, hence it only works on one table.

You can try something like this:

```js
$('#dev-table-filter, #nav-table').keyup(function() {
  filter(this);
});

function filter(self) {
  var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(self).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
    text;
  $(self).find('tbody tr').show().filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
  }).hide();
}
```